# check for generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I want to check if a generic variable is of a certain type but don't want to check the generic part.

Let's say I have a variable of `List<int>` and another of `List<double>`. I just want to check if it is of type `List<>`

```
if(variable is List) {}
```

And not

```
if (variable is List<int> || variable is List<double>) {}
```

is this  possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
variable.GetType().IsGenericType && 
            variable.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)
```

Of course, this only works if variable is of type `List<T>`, and isn't a derived class. If you want to check if it's `List<T>` or inherited from it, you should traverse the inheritance hierarchy and check the above statement for each base class:

```
static bool IsList(object obj)
{
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    do {
        if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
            return true;
        t = t.BaseType;
    } while (t != null);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: GetGenericTypeDefinition() is a bit more natural than MakeGenericType() without arguments.

Comment: Yeah. The complete code is the second one. The first line just focuses on the idea.

Answer (score 6):

You can test an *exact* type via reflection:

```
    object list = new List<int>();

    Type type = list.GetType();
    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("is a List-of-" + type.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name);
    }
```

Personally, though, I'd look for `IList<T>` - more versatile than the concrete `List<T>`:

```
    foreach (Type interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces())
    {
        if (interfaceType.IsGenericType
            && interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
            == typeof(IList<>))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Is an IList-of-" +
                interfaceType.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: marc , isn't `type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)` is enough to check ?

Comment: @Royi if you mean the first block of code, then no: `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` will throw if it isn't a generic type; if you mean the second block: there are more types of "list" than just `List<T>`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Type t = variable.GetType();
if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
{
    // do something
}
```